# Using print dialog from applet makes browser window unresponsive

Tags: java, internet-explorer, printing, applet

I have a ten-year-old applet that wraps itself around the Crystal Reports Viewer applet in order to handle some custom features.  It has worked satisfactorily, displaying and printing reports as designed. The web-app provides data selection, and then generates the HTML to invoke the applet with the correct parameters via an AJAX call.

I have *one* user (so far) who experiences the following problem: after generating the applet and viewing the reports, she prints the reports. Once the print dialog has appeared, even if it is cancelled, the following things no longer work:

- the *Close* link which is supposed to clear out the generated applet HTML no longer works;
- the navigation links to other pages no longer work: they dim appropriately when the mouse hovers over them, but the browser does not respond to clicking on them;
- the window cannot be closed, whether

- by clicking the **X** in the upper-right-hand corner,
- by clicking on the system menu and selecting *Close*,
- by right-clicking on the entry in the task bar and selecting *Close*, or
- by trying to invoke the File/Exit menu item (I believe the File menu is disabled);

- clicking on the window title-bar no longer makes it appear active.

In order to close the window, one has to start the *Task Manager* and end the iexplore process.

It may be that this is another occasion where the applet is retaining focus and it should not: similar bugs such as

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4838000

are reported as being folded into a bug I can no longer find in the Java bug base:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4918282

There are also reports of invisible applets retaining focus: it might be that the custom applet is invoking the original Crystal Reports applet in some way, but I didn't myself develop this code, just the wrapper that drives it.

I do not believe I have a case where a dialog of some sort is appearing behind the IE window; I should think that would occur on more than one system, and this appears to be unique to this user, but the system looks like one of our stock images.

There are also reports of printing locking up an IE window until printing is complete, where the solution is to put the printing into another thread.  In my case, it is unnecessary to actually print: invoking the *Print* dialog and then cancelling it is enough to cause the buggy behavior.

I would like to understand what's going on here, and get things running for this user if possible.  I'd appreciate any reports of similar experiences, or directions to look that I've so far missed.

Some version notes:

- **Win XP Pro:** 5.1.2700 SP 2 Build 2600
- **IE:** 7.0.5730.13
- **Java JRE:** 1.6.0_31-b05
- **Printer:** Imagistics 2500 USB printer (on the off chance)